# vb net cannot catch 'n. def' using Try Catch

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb .net (Visual Studio 2013) and have to perform some mathematical operations in a fast Loop (0.000001 s): I get 'n. def' as result. I want o find out where the error occurs to be able to fix it; I tried using Try ... Catch but did not succed. What else can I try?
Thanks for any help

Here some code as help:

```
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'                                   Lateral Segment Area Case 4
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' LateralSegmentArea4: lateral segment area type 4
''' </summary>
''' <param name="y">crcle radius</param>
''' <param name="xm">radius of screw circle</param>
''' <param name="na">number of screws</param>
''' <param name="Fa">area calculated</param>
''' <param name="Test">Test: true|false</param>
''' <param name="destination">logging path</param>
''' <returns>status</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function LateralSegmentArea4(y As Double,
                                          xm As Double,
                                          na As Double,
                                          ByRef Fa As Double,
                                          Test As Boolean,
                                          destination As String) As Boolean

    Dim ret As Boolean = True
    Dim status As Boolean = True
    Dim logstr As String = String.Empty
    Dim psi As Double = 0
    Dim ym As Double = 0
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    Dim alpha1 As Double = 0
    Dim alpha2 As Double = 0
    Dim phi As Double = 0
    Dim x1 As Double = 0
    Dim y1 As Double = 0
    Dim x2 As Double = 0
    Dim y2 As Double = 0
    Dim Aseg As Double = 0
    Dim result As Double = 0

    Try
        ' psi
        psi = 360 / na

        ' crosspoints x1, x2
        ret = General.CrosspointsCircleStraightline(xm, ym, y, psi / 2, x2, x1, found, destination)
        If found = True Then
            y1 = Math.Tan(psi / 2 * Math.PI / 180) * x1
            y2 = Math.Tan(psi / 2 * Math.PI / 180) * x2

            ' phi
            alpha1 = Math.Asin(y1 / y)
            If x2 >= xm Then
                alpha2 = Math.Asin(y2 / y)
            Else
                alpha2 = Math.PI - Math.Asin(y2 / y)
            End If
            phi = Math.PI - alpha1 - alpha2

            ' segment area
            Aseg = Math.Pow(y, 2) / 2 * (phi - Math.Sin(phi))

            ' lateral area
            result = 2 * Aseg
            Fa = result

            If Test Then
                Logging.WriteLogFile("", False, destination)
                Logging.WriteLogFile("LateralSegmentArea4", False, destination)
                Logging.WriteLogFile("x1: " & x1, False, destination)
                Logging.WriteLogFile("y1: " & y1, False, destination)
                Logging.WriteLogFile("x2: " & x2, False, destination)
                Logging.WriteLogFile("alpha1: " & alpha1, False, destination)
                Logging.WriteLogFile("alpha2: " & alpha2, False, destination)
                Logging.WriteLogFile("phi: " & phi, False, destination)
                Logging.WriteLogFile("Aseg: " & Aseg, False, destination)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        logstr = "Error while getting lateral segment area 4 (" & ex.ToString & ")"
        Logging.WriteLogFile(logstr, True, destination)
        status = False
    End Try

    If status = True Then status = ret
    Return status
End Function
```

' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                                   Crosspoints Circle Straight line
    ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' 
    ''' CrosspointsCircleStraightline: determines crosspoint of circle and straight line
    ''' 
    ''' x-position of srew circle
    ''' y-position of srew circle
    ''' circle radius
    ''' angle of straight line
    ''' x1-crosspoint
    ''' x2-crosspoint
    ''' crosspoint found: true | false
    ''' logging path
    ''' status
    ''' 
    Public Shared Function CrosspointsCircleStraightline(xm As Double,
                                                                 ym As Double,
                                                                 r As Double,
                                                                 phi As Double,
                                                                 ByRef x1 As Double,
                                                                 ByRef x2 As Double,
                                                                 ByRef found As Boolean,
                                                                 destination As String) As Boolean

```
    Dim ret As Boolean = True
    Dim status As Boolean = True
    Dim logstr As String = String.Empty
    Dim a As Double = 0
    Dim part0 As Double = 0
    Dim part1 As Double = 0
    Dim part2 As Double = 0
    Dim part3 As Double = 0
    Dim part4 As Double = 0
    Dim angle As Double = 0

    Try
        found = False
        angle = phi * Math.PI / 180
        a = Math.Tan(angle)

        ' part0 = 2*xm + 2*a*ym
        part0 = 2 * xm + 2 * a * ym

        ' part1 = (2*xm + 2*a*ym)^2
        part1 = Math.Pow((2 * xm + 2 * a * ym), 2)

        ' part2 = 4*(1+a^2)*(xm^2+ym^2-r^2)
        part2 = 4 * (1 + Math.Pow(a, 2)) * (Math.Pow(xm, 2) + Math.Pow(ym, 2) - Math.Pow(r, 2))

        ' part3 = 2*(1+a^2)
        part3 = 2 * (1 + Math.Pow(a, 2))

        'part4 = (2*xm + 2*a*ym)^2 - 4*(1+a^2)*(xm^2+ym^2-r^2)
        part4 = part1 - part2
        If part4 < 0 Then
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            ' repeat
            part4 = part1 - part2
        End If

        ' crosspoint found?
        If part4 > 0 Then
            found = True
            x1 = (part0 + Math.Sqrt(part4)) / part3
            x2 = (part0 - Math.Sqrt(part4)) / part3
        Else
            found = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        logstr = "Error while finding cross points (" & ex.ToString & ")"
        Logging.WriteLogFile(logstr, True, destination)
        status = False
    End Try

    If status = True Then status = ret
    Return status
End Function
```

Comment: some code might be useful...

Comment: ' crosspoints x1, x2
            ret = General.CrosspointsCircleStraightline(xm, ym, y, psi / 2, x2, x1, found, destination)
            If found = True Then
                y1 = Math.Tan(psi / 2 * Math.PI / 180) * x1
                y2 = Math.Tan(psi / 2 * Math.PI / 180) * x2

                ' phi
                alpha1 = Math.Asin(y1 / y)
                If x2 >= xm Then
                    alpha2 = Math.Asin(y2 / y)
                Else
                    alpha2 = Math.PI - Math.Asin(y2 / y)
                End If
                phi = Math.PI - alpha1 - alpha2

Comment: Please post the code in the question so it is formatted correctly

Comment: Gert, welcome to stackoverflow but you should read the details of how to ask an answerable question. Please start with the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot catch 'n. def' using Try Catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745041/cannot-catch-n-def-using-try-catch)